# Meta tag code is breaking and showing in wordpress site's header

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, meta-tags

I'm using the following code to autogenerate my posts metatags:

```
function gretathemes_meta_description() {
    global $post;
    if ( is_singular() ) {
        $des_post = strip_tags( $post->post_content );
        $des_post = strip_shortcodes( $post->post_content );
        $des_post = str_replace( array("\n", "\r", "\t"), ' ', $des_post );
        $des_post = mb_substr( $des_post, 0, 300, 'utf8' );
        print '<meta name="description" content="' . $des_post . '" />' . "\n";
    }
    if ( is_home() ) {
        print '<meta name="description" content="' . get_bloginfo( "description" ) . '" />' . "\n";
    }
    if ( is_category() ) {
        $des_cat = strip_tags(category_description());
        print '<meta name="description" content="' . $des_cat . '" />' . "\n";
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'gretathemes_meta_description');
function gretathemes_meta_tags() {
    print '<meta name="meta_name" content="meta_value" />';
}
add_action('wp_head', 'gretathemes_meta_tags');
```

The problem is:
In some posts that code is breaking the meta tag code, and what's happening is that part of the first paragraph of the post is showing up on the top of the website (header). This is the output that I'm getting:

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="1667889836683276" /><meta property="og:title" content="+ de 180 Sites &#038; Ferramentas de SEO [2022]: A lista definitiva (Revisados e Avaliados)"/><meta property="og:type" content="article"/><meta property="og:url" content="https://lucrebem.com.br/emp-digital/ferramentas-seo/"/><meta property="og:site_name" content="Lucre Bem"/><meta property="og:image" content="https://lucrebem.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/office-620817_960_7201-300x199.jpg"/>
```

This does not happen in every post. This is one of the pages where it is happening: https://lucrebem.com.br/emp-digital/ferramentas-seo/

Comment: You need to sanitize the values you are putting into the html attributes. WordPress has docs on this. This function may help https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/esc_attr/. Also I don't think that php's built-in strip tags function makes things very safe for printing into html attributes. Read more on the PHP docs page (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)

Comment: Also, that doesn't mean strip tags cannot be useful in this context, but it's just not sufficient for assuming its output doesn't contain html or other html characters.

Comment: Lastly, if your not understanding why the first paragraph is showing up on the page, then you should probably also read up on and understand XSS.

Comment: This code is all over the internet in blogs related to wordpress development, I didn't expect it to be that dangerous.

Comment: It's not necessarily dangerous but potentially could be if you have contributor users on your site that are supposed to have less priveledges than admin users. I'm pretty sure strip tags does not strip self closing tags such as img tags, and you can add the onLoad attribute to an image tag to execute arbitrary javascript, even also put no src on the image tag so that users can't even see it. The paragraph shows up because $des_post contains non-escaped double quotes most likely, or possibly double quote followed by right angle bracket.

Comment: Is there any alternative without a plugin then? All I need is to autogenerate metatags.

How about this?   `$des_post = str_replace( array( "\\n", "\\r", "\\t" ), ' ', $des_post);`

Comment: Just use  esc_attr( $des_post ). It should more or less work, and not have security problems.

Comment: @JoelM Hey, question: can I use esc_html instead? It seems like it's safer, although I'm not seeing any difference. Mind explaining about it? I'm just asking...